# react-native-sqlite-storage android.useDeprecatedNdk NdkCompile is no longer supported

Tags: sqlite, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

I am using react native 0.61.5. I am getting this error in my console.

```
> Configure project :react-native-sqlite-storage
WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.useDeprecatedNdk
NdkCompile is no longer supported
```

I am beginner in react-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NdkCompile` is no longer supported

In my case, that was an `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`

You can add in your `android/gradle.properties` like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```